# Lexical or predecessor issue for Firebase Firestore and Protobuf, these two folders are the issue

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

Non-portable path to file ''; specified path differs in case from file name on disk

I've tried reinstalling pods, changing deployment etc, created a new project and transferred files to have the same issue with Firestore. I've been on this issue since yesterday.

This is in the uneditable file.
There are now 3 duplicated issues for each and growing every time I clean and build.

## if GPB_USE_PROTOBUF_FRAMEWORK_IMPORTS

#import Protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>

#import Protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>

#import Protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>

## else

#import "google/protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h"

#import "google/protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h"

#import "google/protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h"

Non-portable path to file ''; specified path differs in case from file name on disk

My project builds and runs fine.

It's just the bunch of warnings that is concerning me.

If you can explain the issue to me I would be grateful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either ignore the warning or disable it by adding `pod 'Protobuf', :inhibit_warnings => true` to the Podfile.

The root cause is this [radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6091887509241856). More discussion at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2665

Comment: I find it hard ignoring the warnings. Installing pod 'Protobuf', :inhibit_warnings => true removed more than half of the warnings but didn't remove any of the same warnings from the FirebaseFirestore folder. I added , :inhibit_warnings => true after the other few remaining pods but it did nothing.